# ActivityNotFoundException calling an intent on android

Tags: android, android-manifest, activitynotfoundexception

When I try to execute this code I get an ActivityNotFoundException ,I think it's because I'm trying to call an activity which is not in the manifest but i don't know what I have to add to the  manifest file.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
       Uri path=Uri.parse("android.resource://com.android.was4fi/"+R.drawable.miarchivo);
       Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
       intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the problem is not in your manifest file. You are trying to use implicit intent and Android system can't find activity that can handle  this intent. Read more on http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ExampleSend. Also this code should be wrapped in try/catch block.